# bash script using properties - prop is empty when adding chracters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

`inputs.properties:`

```
app_name=magic
```

`bash script: (test2.sh)`

```
#!/bin/bash
. inputs.properties
echo $app_name
echo "${app_name}-abracadabra"
APP_NAME="not-magic"
echo "${APP_NAME}-abracadabra"
```

output:

```
[root@mymachine testdir]# ./test2.sh 
magic
-abracadabra
not-magic-abracadabra
```

first echo prints the word "magic" taken from the prop file
second echo prints only the added string but not name_app value
third echo shows the differance when adding a string to a local variable it is printed as it should.

I am using alot of properties from a property file but when I try to use a take some props together with some text, the value of the prop disappers.

The same problem happened when I first used a parser that receives a property file and  property name as inputs and echos out the value.

I used this arser in oreder to get the prop but same result, I get the value but it diappears when chaning a string to it.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

. inputs.properties
echo $app_name
echo "${app_name}-abracadabra"
APP_NAME="not magic"
echo "${APP_NAME}-abracadabra"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inputs.properties` contains DOS line endings (`\r\n`). The actual value of `app_name` is `magic\r`. When you try to echo that, the `\r` causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, and `-abracadabra` overwrites the initial part. Try `echo ${app_name}-hi` to see the effect.

If you can't (or don't want to) edit `input.properties`, you can strip the trailing carriage return with

```
app_name=${app_name%$'\r'}
```

Comment: +1. Very good, I should have thought about that straight away but I didn't ^^. Well done!

Comment: @user2183505: you could have seen it by :   `./test2.sh | cat -ve` (-e adds "$" at end of each line, and -v displays non-printable ascii characters as "^something")